# 50 reputation to comment on answer to 'The Programming Language Quiz'?

Tags: support, reputation

I want to comment the language of a code snippet found on [The Programming Language Quiz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54807/the-programming-language-quiz), but I can't, because I don't have enough reputation. I've tried it in the programming language that I think it is, and it has worked.

Isn't the 50 reputation minimum unfair?

Comment: Yes, in this case the limit is a bit annoying. If you'd like, I can post the comment for you and credit you so the poster is aware you cracked it. Alternatively, you could probably try to talk to them in [The Nineteenth Byte](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte).

Comment: The answer has been suggested. Thanks though, @Vioz-!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In short: yes, I think it is unfair.

However, this is a quirk for this specific puzzle, due to answers being in comment form. The fifty reputation limit is network wide, and not something easily changeable (especially for a single post).

In the future, I'd like to see an alternative to comment-answers, but I'm not sure exactly what form that would take right now.

Comment: Of course, that alternative solution already exists: post a separate thread for the robbers as we've done several times in the past. In this case, I decided against doing that because I figured most answers would not consist of any more than a (potentially guessed) language name, so the robbers' contributions wouldn't be interesting enough for full answers. However, I didn't consider the side effect of introducing a 50-rep barrier for robbers, which is indeed a bit unfortunate.

Comment: @MartinBüttner I thought about mentioning that, but I agree that it would have been overkill for this challenge in particular. It's awkward as it is on most CnRs, so I'm hoping for a better alternative to emerge.

Comment: @Geobits Apart from maybe something in chat, I can't see an alternative to comments and/or answers.